# Jquery UI droppable action when snapped in

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I wan that an event starts wenn droppable element snapps in?

is there any possibility to realise this?

Js looks like this at the moment:

```
function MatchingTask(questions, answers) {
    // Elemente Drag n Drop faehig machen
    $(".match_task_draggable").draggable({
        cursor: 'move',
        containment: $('.match_task_draggable').parent('div').parent('div'),
        scroll: false,
        snap: ".match_task_drop",
        snapMode: "inner",
        stop: setDroppableAnswer
    });
}

// Set Answer
function setDroppableAnswer(){
    alert("Ba");
}
```

But stop reacts every time I drop an element, it should only react when it is dropped to the snap area

Solution:

```
$(".match_task_drop").droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        setDroppableAnswer( ui.draggable );
    }
});
```

Comment: do I set a droppable ?

Comment: ok droppable is the solution

Comment: looks like it's just you here all over the question. :D